# Vba range pairwise division

Tags: vba, excel

I have a set of variable ranges and I want to do pairwise division of each of the members of each range and bold the member or two highest members if there is a difference of 3/1

Example 1

```
Column A.   Ferrets.  Rabbits. Foxes.            
Column B. 3000 1000 4000
```

Because Ferrets and Foxes are in greater than 3/1 proportion to rabbits bold them

Example 2

```
Column A. Ferrets. Rabbits. Foxes.            
Column B 1000 1000 4000
```

Because foxes are in greater than 3/1 proportion to ferrets and rabbits bold them

Example 3

```
Column A.  Ferrets.  Rabbits. Foxes.            
Column B. 3000 3500 4000
```

Bold nothing

I can get the logic to bold but im not quite sure where to begin to get excel to loop through all the possible divisions.  Note the range will vary with the number of rows.  Sometimes up to 5 and 6 or maybe more which is why im having the problem.

Comment: It looks like you are looking for a vba solution - do you have any code already?

Answer (score 0):

I only have a do loop to count the number of cells in the range.  This gives the number of columns that is contained in the range.  What I do not know how to do is then take and store a double of whatever division may come from all the pairwise divisions.  So if it were 2 rows there would be two answers, 3 rows and there would be 6, 4 and there would be 12...i think the function will be n(n-1) now that i think about it.

```
Option Explicit

Sub Bold()

Dim i, j As Integer
i = 2  'Row
j = 3  'Column


Do
    If Cells(i,j).Value <>"" Then
        i = i + 1
    End If

Loop Until Cells(i, j).Value = ""
i = i - 1
```

I figure it would be some sort of nested loop but I'm not quite sure where to start with the function on the number of rows.

Comment: Don't post additional info as an answer, edit it into your _question_